# ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground not visible enough on a dark background

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

On Android Lollipop, I'm using:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

to have the material animated feedback when I click on a button.

It works well when I have a button contained in a white/light layout, like a CardView for example.

But when I want to use the same thing on a dark background, we barely see the effect, it is not visible enough.

Does someone have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: The easiest way is just to set the theme for the entire dark-background container. This is how we handle Light.DarkActionBar. What's your target API?

Comment: Thank you. My target API is 21 (I wouldn't be able to have the material animated feedback if otherwise) and I've got two versions of the button, one for API<21, one for API21. What do you mean by setting the theme for the dark-background container?

Comment: On API 21+ you can set android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark" on a view or view group to change all of the theme attributes (text color, ripple color, button color, etc.) to the "dark" versions. If you set it on a view group, the theme is also applied to all of the child elements during view inflation. It's an easy way to have regions of "dark" in an otherwise "light" interface (or vice versa).

Comment: ... oh, and bonus question: do you know how can I make this background have rounded corners?

Comment: You'd need to set up a custom <ripple> drawable. There are a bunch of SO questions for that or you can just check the RippleDrawable javadocs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On API 21+ you can set `android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark"` on a `View` or `ViewGroup` to change all of the theme attributes (text color, ripple color, button color, etc.) to the "dark" versions. If you set it on a `ViewGroup`, the theme is also applied to all of the child elements during inflation. It's an easy way to have regions of "dark" in an otherwise "light" interface (or vice versa).

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/my_dark_layout"
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/my_dark_bounded_ripple"
        ...
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="Bounded ripple" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/my_dark_unbounded_ripple"
        ...
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@drawable/my_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: somehow it doesn't work if imagebutton has `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"` and `android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`. Do You know why?

Comment: I feel like Views in an app should respect the `theme` attribute set in the `application` tag in the manifest, even if they aren't part of an Activity (screen overlays). But I guess this is just another Google thing.

Answer (score 6):

Solution with AppCompat (works on old APIs too)

```
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: Can be added as part of style <style name="AppTheme.Button.Borderless" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
        <item name="android:theme">@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/button_height</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_s</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to change the app theme:

```
Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar
```

It works fine for me.