# my ImageButton lose it's animation effect on adding background color

Tags: android

whenever i set `android:background`="colorxxx" for my `ImageButton`, the effect of pressing `ImageButton` will lost.

before adding that attribute it has an effect filling the image with dark color
i want it works too when `ImageButton` has `android:background`="colorxxx"

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/a"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/b"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/c"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/d"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the code for @drawable/c?

Comment: @RohitSharma, It's an image not a code

Comment: please post relevent code

Comment: You mean ripple effect for your button disappear after set color ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ripple effect is part of the background, like `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`, if you set a background yourself, the ripple will no longer work.

You can instead change the tint of your button as stated in [this other response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959610/apply-material-design-touch-ripple-to-imagebutton)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by adding android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" insted of color hex

Link: [Apply Material Design Touch Ripple to ImageButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959610/apply-material-design-touch-ripple-to-imagebutton)